# Get list of all Active Directories in Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

How can I get a list of all the Active Directories in Azure **using powershell**? To be more precise, I am looking for the following information which is available in the Azure Portal [The following two entries] :

[image]

Also, how can I get detailed information of each of those two directories in **powershell**?
(I have already installed the [Azure Active Directory Cmdlets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Both options below will retrieve the available tenants, however the Azure AD Cmdlet will provide a little more information such as the Display Name and Verified Domains of the tenants.

**Azure AD Modules**

Cmdlet: `Get-AzureADTenantDetail -All $true`

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadtenantdetail

**Azure Rm Modules**

Cmdlet:`Get-AzureRmTenant`

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/get-azurermtenant

**Testing:**

If you want to try these Cmdlets without needing to install them locally, check out Azure Cloud Shell. It'll provide you with a browser based Command Line for Microsoft Azure.

https://shell.azure.com

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/cloud-shell/